# how to calculate <td> values into one input field?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

I am having table with two td values

```
  <td><?php echo $row['remun'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['lum'];?></td>
```

it return some values based on row value

```
for example
Ist column   2nd column
100              150
200              150
300              150
```

`<input type="text"  name="grand_total" id="grand_total" />`

javascript

```
   <script>    
  $('#dynamic-table tr').each(function() {
   if (!this.rowIndex) return; // skip first row
   var customerId = this.cells[4].innerHTML;
   alert(customerId);
  $("#grand_total").val(customerId);
 });
```

i get only first row value but i want sum of all fields.

Comment: `<td><?php echo $row['remun']+$row['lum'];?></td>`

Comment: You want to get column wise grand total or all columns all together grand total?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i want sum of two colum total output=1050 .

Comment: You need to sum using php, js or indifferent?

Comment: need js only ...

Comment: Then why is not js tagged? And why is PHP tagged?

Comment: post changed   ....

Comment: let me guess if i'am not wrong...you want some thing like this
col A,           col B,        Col A+b
1           ,         10    ,      11
2           ,          5     ,      7
          ,Sum Of A+B  18

Answer (score 0):

But you can easily manage it from your php loop as well as.
definitely, you are using for loop to printing record in table.

```
<?php 
   $grand_total=0;          
  foreach($a as $row){ 
  $grand_total=$grand_total+$row['remun']+$row['lum'];
   ?>
 <td class="remun"><?php echo $row['remun'];?></td>
 <td class="lum"><?php echo $row['lum'];?></td>
 <?php }?>
 <td class="total"><?php echo $grand_total;?></td>
```

But if you want to do it with js then please follow the below once.
Please add some class in your  like below.

```
 <td class="remun"><?php echo $row['remun'];?></td>
 <td class="lum"><?php echo $row['lum'];?></td>
```

Now user below jquery code for the Sum of both.

```
var t1=0;
var t2=0;
var t3=0;
$('.remun').each(function(){
 t1=t1+parseInt($(this).html());
});
$('.lum').each(function(){
 t2=t2+parseInt($(this).html());
});
t3=t1+t2;
alert(t3);
```